# How to see full round trip price in Google Flights?

Tags: google-flights

I am using Date Grid and it looks like showing roundtrip price, because it depends on both back and forth date.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I choose this and when I choose cheapes flight on next page

[image]

I am then presented with Returning flight page

[image]

which doubles my price

[image]

My questions are:

1. If presented prices are in one direction, then what is the purpose of `Date Grid`? Why does price in it depends on returning date if it should be only dependence on departure date?
2. If the price is for round trip, then how to get it ($2600 not $5800)?

Answer (score 0):

The prices shown in the date grid are the roundtrip prices. I don't know where you got this screenshot

[image]

because 2655 + 2655 = 5310 EUR, which is far from 5845 EUR. That seems to be a different flight. Post a video showing how you got this flight price if you need further help.

Note that in some rare occasions, prices shown in the date grid can be unavailable, but that's not your case.